# What's the quickest way with SQL to insert a bunch of rows

Tags: sql, insert, sybase, bulkinsert

I have an array of numbers in memory and I need to put them in a temp table so I can join against other tables. The list can be 5 or it can be 250000.
I can do one insert at a time, but I was wondering if there was any sql trick where I could insert 100 at a time with some insert into  select....  kind of thing that I'm not thinking of.

The bulk uploader (in sybase) is not an option because there's no java implementation for it, and shelling to bcp is not an option either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try JDBC batch insert. I never worked with Sybase but this works with MySql, Postgres and Oracle as well.

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (1000, 'Joe Jones')");
stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO departments VALUES (260, 'Shoe')");
stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO emp_dept VALUES (1000, 260)");

// submit a batch of update commands for execution
int[] updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch();
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html

Comment: Does this still scale to 250,000 inserts in a single batch?

Comment: It may. It depends on the size of one statement. You'll have to try it for yourself. As you increase the batch size, at one point you'll end up with OutOfMemory. On a normal PC with 1G mem dedicated to my application (Xmx), I usually use 50k batchsize. I found there was no significant difference between 50k and 100k: For 1M records, it is almost the same whether you have 10 or 20 round-trip between the application and the database.

Comment: batches of anything more than 1 will be a vast improvement. Thanks.

Comment: basically it's the back and forth and back and forth to the server I'm trying to avoid.